# list.add(element) unsupported operation exception

Tags: java, list, arraylist

```
info.add(("§eEntity Type: §f" + e.getType()));
```

This line throws an unsupported operation exception. e is an object of class Entity, and info is a List Initialized like this:

```
List<String> info = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Why is this happening?

The full stack trace is: http://pastebin.com/XC996QFS
(I have added text to identify the most interesting line of the trace)

The API I am working from is linked in a comment towards the top of the source code.

The full source code is: http://pastebin.com/VEQYGGrM

Comment: Post the full stack trace.

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't later reassigned a value (such as from Arrays.asList())?

Comment: (And what are the extra `()` for?)

Comment: Most likely your stack trace is trying to tell you are using a different List class.

Comment: I have edited the OP with links to the stack trace and full source code. I apologize for being so vague earlier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this to happen then either:

`info` is not actually an `ArrayList` and has had a different list assigned to it at some point (for example `Collections.emptyList`, `Collections.singletonList`, `Arrays.asList`, wrapping it in an immutable list of some sort, etc).

or

`e.getType()` is throwing the exception.

The exception stack trace will help you confirm which of these is the case.

Comment: how can `e.getType()` throwing exception would result in unsupported operation exception?

Comment: @zencv `public Type getType() {throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}`

Comment: @zencv if e.getType() is throwing the exception itself or is calling a method (however indirectly) that throws the exception. It can be surprising how these things happen through very unexpected routes sometimes.

Comment: I have removed all Arrays.asList() bits, as they are not necessary and can easily be replaced (and probably should be) with new ArrayList<String>();. I will test the plugin now.

Comment: @TimB Thank you for your help. There was a stray Arrays.asList() as you expected. After removing it, the expected behavior surfaced.

The working source is here, if anyone is curious: http://pastebin.com/7CXKCKKd